# Grouping Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

So I've created 4 nuget packages (pack1,pack2,pack3 and pack4). In some projects I only need one of them but in others I need them all.

Is there a way to create a "fake" package that automatically install all these 4 automatically? Or do I need to create an empty solution, add these 4 as dependencies and generate the nuget from here?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried creating a package with no content files of its own (as per its Xml definition), but with the 4 packages as dependencies?

Comment: You can use [this beautiful tool](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) to create packages without creating an empty project. Add the four other packages as dependencies and you'll be fine.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Creating a porject and package with no content and only those 4 dependencies works as expected. I am only asking if there is already a feature that let's me group 4 pakcages into a virtual one.